# Single Command to call different commands in different View Models

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5, command

Putting my requirement in very easy steps. Searched a lot on web but got very confused.

I got a Main Window (.xaml)
I got a Menu control, with Save option (a user control)
I got 3 more user controls (.xaml) in the same Window inside the Tab Control (with 3 tabs).

Each user control has data entries and has its own View Model class with Save() methods to save the data (implemented ICommand and INotifiyPropertyChanged in view model).

Now, if I have save button in individual usercontrol (inside the tabs) it works fine (I used commands for achieving this). But, I need the, Save to work, just clicking the "Save" on the menu, which is also a usercontrol and is inside the Main Window. The Menu save should act like a common Save for all the 3 user controls.

So the Menu should be now smart to identify which is the active usercontrol (probably based on the tab changed event or something else) and accordingly fire the Save() method for that usercontrol in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to accomplish communication between parts of your application without tightly coupling them.